# Flutter fetch api index

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I want to retrieve the next address recount shipto 0 .
I can only retrieve shipto 0 .
When it comes up with more than 1 address ,
it will recount shipto 0 . Sorry , I am practicing

I can't fetch the next address

but I can fetch sequence shipto 0

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

This is fetchapi

```
var loading = false;
Future fetchMos() async {
List<Item> listitem = [];
listitem.clear();
loading = true;
var client = http.Client();
String mosUrl =
  '';
 var url = Uri.parse(mosUrl);
 var headers = {
'Client-Token': '',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 };
var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
var data = jsonDecode((utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)))['items'];
for (var index in data) {
  listitem.add(Item.fromJson(index));
  print(data);
}
loading = false;
}
return listitem;
}
```

This is Json

```
   {
        "items": [
 {
    "custnum": "",
    "name": "",
    "address": [
        {
            "shipto": 0,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
           "shipto": 1,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
            "shipto": 2,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
            "shipto": 3,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        }
         {
        "custnum": "",
        "name": "",
        "address": [
           {
            "shipto": 0,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
        {
           "shipto": 1,
            "addr1": "",
            "thanon": "",
            "tambon": "",
            "amphur": "",
            "prov_code": "",
            "province": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": "",
            "contact": "",
            "postcode": ""
        },
    ]
}
],
```

Comment: do you want to iterate over the ["adress"] list, right ?

Comment: Post Item class code